# Like button on ListView all triggered when i press one like button flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I try to make an post app so the user can comment, like, and share the post. so, the app will show all post from the database that i had. And the problem is all likes button from the all post going red when i just pressed one of them. Any ideas how to fix the like button on my listview?
here is my code:

```
ListView.builder(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: storyList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 18.0, right: 18.0, top: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade300)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 15,
                              top: 8,
                              right: 15,
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Color(0xffFEF8EC),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(20))),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                        backgroundImage: MemoryImage(
                                            showImage(storyList[index]
                                                ['userImg'])) //here
                                        )),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        storyList[index]['username'],
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        getTimeDifferenceFromNow(
                                            storyList[index]['postTime']),
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12.0,
                                            color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                150, 0, 0, 0)),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 500,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 15,
                              top: 15,
                              right: 15,
                              bottom: 10,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              storyList[index]['postMsg'],
                              maxLines: null,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
                          ),
                          storyList[index]['postImg'] != null &&
                                  storyList[index]['postImg'] != "null"
                              ? GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    showImageViewer(
                                        context,
                                        Image.memory(showImage(
                                                storyList[index]
                                                    ['postImg']))
                                            .image,
                                        swipeDismissible: false);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                      width: 500,
                                      height: 300,
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 15,
                                        top: 15,
                                        right: 15,
                                        bottom: 10,
                                      ),
                                      child: Image.memory(
                                          showImage(
                                              storyList[index]['postImg']),
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          gaplessPlayback: true)),
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: 200,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 8,
                                top: 10,
                                right: 0,
                                bottom: 10,
                              ),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 5, left: 8),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                            child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Image.asset(
                                              "assets/Comment_icon.png",
                                              width: 25,
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      left: 2),
                                              child: Text("1"),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        )),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 20),
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                isLiked == false
                                                    ? Icon(
                                                        Icons
                                                            .favorite_border_outlined,
                                                        color: Colors
                                                            .grey
                                                            .shade500,
                                                      )
                                                    : Icon(
                                                        Icons.favorite,
                                                        color: Colors
                                                            .pinkAccent,
                                                      ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 2),
                                                  child: Text(""),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              left: 20),
                                          child: Container(
                                              child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Icon(
                                                Icons.share,
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                                                size: 20,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
```

Any help will be valuable for me thank you.

Comment: Not sure because the code seems incomplete, but you probably are setting a variable "isLiked" and checking it with all rows. If you set "isLiked" at a click, and that same var is checked on all rows, then the condition will be the same for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using same `isLiked` variable for all list items use it with your `storyList` array.

Add another key to your array list for `isLiked`.

Redesign your `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`
eg.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> storyList = [
    {
      'username': 'username',
      'userImg': 'userImg',
      'postTime': 'postTime',
      'postMsg': 'postMsg',
      'postImg': 'postImg',
      'isLiked': true,
    },
  ];
```

and use this `isLiked` key for update your list items